# PDFBox IOException: End of File, expected line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pdfbox

I am currently trying to grab text from a PDF that is already uploaded and accessed through a link by using PDFBox and Selenium.
I used this as a source: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-extract-pdf-text-and-verify-using-selenium-webdriver-java

```
public String function(String pdf_url) {
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pDoc;
    COSDocument cDoc;
    String parsedText = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(pdf_url);
        BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(file);
        parser.parse();
        cDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);

        pDoc = new PDDocument(cDoc);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pDoc);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return parsedText;
}

Error: End-of-File expected line
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1519)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:372)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:186)
at scripts.Script.grabPDF_Text(Script.java:94)
at scripts.Script.main(Script.java:817)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: what is the return type of this method ?

Comment: String, sorry I omitted it on accident. I updated the original post.

Comment: I tried this and it works, only difference is I've read pdf from local. now, what is the pdf_url has ?

Comment: It's a link to a PDF that is directly uploaded to the server. I access the pdf using the link and it shows like if I opened it using acrobat. This is a String that I passed in from the main.  Thanks for testing it out yourself. It's kinda like this file: https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

Comment: would it be easier if I just downloaded the file and read it that way? since you confirmed that it works,

Comment: This code works for the PDF in a URL as well. I think there must be something in your pdf. Anyways give it a try by download and read

Comment: Also, find out on which line you're getting exception.

Comment: The exception occurs on this line: parser.parse();

Comment: Check your URL for any unwanted chars spaces . You might have to debug that

Comment: An "End-of-File" during `PDFParser.parseHeader` sounds like an empty file (or nearly so).

Comment: @Prany Can I see how you passed in the URL for both your examples to work on your end?

Comment: @mkl The page is not empty though.

Comment: The best would be to save what you get with `url.openStream()` into a file to see what's really there. I concur with mkl that your file is empty.

Comment: @stevek - Added as an answer

Comment: Thanks everyone, it turns out it is these PDFs. They are incompatible or is some strange format because I'm able to read different PDFs.

Comment: I was trying to parse 100s of files kept in one directory & I was getting same error for `PDDocument.load()` &  by mistake there was one zero byte non - pdf file  in that directory :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example that you asked to share using  PDFURL

```
string PDFURL = "https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf";
function(PDFURL1);

public String function(String pdf_url)
{
 //Exact same code as yours
}
```

For using PDF as local file, URL and BufferedInputStream needs to be replaced by

```
 File file = new File(pdf_url);
 PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `new PDFParser()` is outdated. Use `PDDocument.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check either files are with size of 0 KB
or
You may check with

```
try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())){
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first parameter is a FileInputStream, verify that it is at beginning.

To be sure, always reset channel position to start:

```
if(inputStream instanceof FileInputStream)
{
    FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) inputStream;
    fis.getChannel().position(0);
}
```